# modal function only showing black screen and not the actually modal,

Tags: javascript, php

my modal won't show up, it's just black screen after clicking the button that opens it, im getting this error on jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/..

the javascript that ive use

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
  var data = {"ID" : ID};
jQuery.ajax({
  url : '/Cybernetics/shop/includes/Modal.php',
  method : "post",
  data : data,
  success : function(data){
    jQuery('body').append(data);
    jQuery('#modalview').modal('toggle');
  },
  error : function(){
    alert("something went wrong!")
  }
});
</script>
```

it works before but it suddenly didn't, anyone got any ideas??? TIA

Comment: Did you check this issue on dev tools? There might not be contents inside modal.

Comment: Can you post what the `data` variable is returning (for `success: function(data)`)? This may help in resolving the issue

Comment: there are contents in the modal, every time i clicked the button that opens i get the error [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/..

Comment: As the error code said you use synchronous  request. Use instead asynchronous by specifying it the jquery ajax method arguments

Comment: sooo, what should i do??? kinda new to this jQuery thing

Comment: Take a look at this page http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ to know more about ajax function parameters. Specially async parameter

Comment: You may also need to wrap your ajax call in $(document ).ready(function(){}) to avoid ajax call while loading the document.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info :)